# How do I package up go code as an arm RPM?

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, rpm, rpmbuild

I've got a go project that I'm building on OSX. I've compiled it for arm linux by using docker to run the linux compiler and GOARCH=arm64 to generate arm code. now I want to package it up as an RPM.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to get rpmbuild to give me an arm package. I've tried setting `--target arm`, `--target arm64`, `--target arm-test-linux`, and `--target arm64-test-linux`

All produce the same result,

`file project.arm.rpm` => `project.arm.rpm: RPM v3.0 bin noarch`

How do I get it to recognize the architecture instead of producing a noarch rpm?

Answer (score 1):

use the `BuildArch` option in your spec file:

```
BuildArch: arm64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rpmbuild -bs project.spec
```

This will create `project.src.rpm`. And then:

```
sudo dnf install qemu-user-static
mock -r fedora-33-aarch64 project.src.rpm
```

which will use this feature: https://github.com/rpm-software-management/mock/wiki/Feature-forcearch
With the recent version of Mock you do not even need to specify `--forcearch` as it automatically detected.

If you omit the `BuildArch` then it will be automatically set using the chroot you use as a parameter for Mock.

BTW here is general guidance about packaging Go as an RPM. https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Golang/